# <a> tag unclickable when using fixed positioning in css class

Tags: html, css, tags

```
#menu {
    height: 265px;
    width: 1013p x;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:0;
    top: 15px;
    left: -37px;
}
```

This is my css class and:

```
<div style="float:right; height: 100px; margin-left: 0px;margin-right:0px; width: 352px;" > 
    <br />       
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a style=" text-decoration:none; color:White" href="#">Site Map</a>
    <div style="height: 26px;margin-top:10px">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
            style="Width:149px;margin-right:2px; margin-left: 30px;"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" Width="55px" />
    </div>   
</div>

<div id="menu"> 
    <ul>
        <li class="nav1" style="margin-left:50px;"><a href="" style="width:201px">&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a></li>                  
        <li class="nav2" style="width:201px; height: 153px;margin-left: 0px;"><a href="" style="width:200px">Products</a></li> 
        <li class="nav3" style="width:200px; height: 153px;margin-left: 0px;"><a href="" style="width:200px">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="nav4" style="width:201px; height: 153px; margin-left: 0px;"><a href="" style="width:200px">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is my html code.The `<a>` tag(Site Map) is unclickable when using `position:fixed` in my css class and acts as if it is just a normal layer. I saw the suggestion of adding `z-index:10;` some where which didn't work for me, I tried changing the z-index to 0 and 101 and changing the position to absolute, but didn't work either.what should I do?

Any ideas will be appreciated,thanks in advance.

Comment: What bit of HTML has the ID #menu ?  I don't see it in your HTML?

Comment: I don't see a Div id menu either.

Comment: sorry,I will edit it right away.

Comment: z-index with value 0 is getting back layer from any other elements. that is why the tag is getting lost it focus. increase z-index value as much as you can.

Comment: I increased it by 100000000000000000 but didn't work either.

Comment: please help,nobody knows what should I do?

Comment: any other places did you put z-index?

Comment: it looks ok, try to remove the style and put an actual link in the href , and z-index:9999;

Comment: no i didn't put z-index in other place Mithun,should I do it?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean konnection,could you please put the code for me?thanks

Comment: i have check it locally but didnt find any prob.. is it your full code?

Comment: no it is not my full code,does it relate to other parts?

Comment: can you see the sitemap link on your page? because it is in white color.

Comment: no it is not white,I can see it of course.

Comment: the sitemap link is not inside of the #menu div then where the prob is arise? so where is the class for sitemap link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your code:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Site Map</a>
    <div>
       TextBox and Button from .asp tags...
    </div>
</div>

<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav1"><a href="http://yahoo.com">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav2"><a href="">Products</a></li>
        <li class="nav3"><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="nav4"><a href="">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I removed all the inline styles (use style sheets, much cleaner) for simplicity.

The CSS is as follows:

```
.wrap {
    float:right; 
    height: 100px; 
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right:0px; 
    width: 352px;
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
    position: relative; /* need this for z-index to take effect */
    z-index: 2;
}

#menu {
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
    height: 265px;
    width: 1013px; /* Fix the typo for px (extra space) */
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

What you have here are two block elements, `div.wrap` and `div#menu`, the first is a static position, in-flow block, and the second is fixed position.

By default, elements are stacked in the order they appear in the DOM, so `div#menu` is stacked over `div.wrap`, and for this reason, you can't click the link since it is behind `div#menu` which may overlap `div.wrap` unless you have a large enough window.

To fix this, use `z-index`, which works only for non-static positioned elements.  In this case, apply `position: relative` to `div.wrap` and then set `z-index: 2`, and for `div#menu`, set `z-index: 1` and the "Site Map" link will be accessible to the mouse for all window widths.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Dg8YN/

**Reference**

For more details about z-index, see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#layers
and http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html